# Can anyone explain me what happened with "GeofenceErrorMessages" class?

Tags: java, android, error-handling, android-geofence

Recently I have read about the ["Create and monitor geofences"](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing#java) section at android developers official website and I found I can't use this section of code:

```
String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
```

Actually my android studio doesn't accept **GeofenceErrorMessages** class and I can't import with ALT+ENTER shortcut because the android studio doesn't recognize this class at all.

I managed to solve the problem with this code but I really want to know what happened with GeofenceErrorMessages class:

```
 String errorMessage = GeofenceStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
```

For GeofenceStatusCodes I used this import:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofenceStatusCodes;
```

QUESTION:

Do I need to import something in a project or **GeofenceErrorMessages class** is maybe deprecated?
I'm using the android studio 3.5.1 version with the newest update.

Answer (score 1):

I ANSWERED ON THIS QUESTION BY MYSELF BECAUSE I THINK MANY DEVELOPER BEGINNERS WIIL SOMETIMES GET STUCK ON SILLY PROBLEMS LIKE THIS ONE.

I just have returned to this section and realized how silly I am. 
GeofenceErrorMessages is not a predefined class provided by an android library it's actually class what you need to create by yourself and you can call it whatever you want.
I was confused because it is presented at official android developer website.

Here is an example code with GeofenceErrorMessages class (you can call it Stupid class if you want):

```
import android.content.Context;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofenceStatusCodes;

public class GeofenceErrorMessages {

public static String getErrorCode(Context context, int errorCode) {

    switch (errorCode) {
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            return "geofence_not_available";
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
            return "geofence_too_many_geofences";
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
            return "geofence_too_many_pending_intents";
        default:
            return "unknown_geofence_error";
    }

}
```

}

You can see here GeofenceStatusCodes class is a predefined class from the android library and I used it to sort different types of geofence status.

Comment: Accept your own answer as the correct answer. You saved me some days of figuring out what the docs said. Also: not Context var needed.